# i am unable to install subzy tool in my linux it shows error

Tags: go, debugging, setuptools

I tried to install this subzy tool from GitHub but it shows this kind of error and I can't install it I have faced the same problem with other programs written in (GO language).

I can clone the programs written in python but I am unable to clone the programs written in go language once I clone I don't know how to install them

[image: 1]

```
****➜  ~ go install -v github.com/lukasikic/subzy@latest
go: finding a module f**or package github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir
go: finding module for package github.com/logrusorgru/aurora
go: found github.com/logrusorgru/aurora in github.com/logrusorgru/aurora v2.0.3+incompatible
go: found github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir in github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir v1.1.0
➜  ~ go get -u -v github.com/lukasikic/subzy
go get: installing executables with 'go get' in module mode is deprecated.
    Use 'go install pkg@version' instead.
    For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
    or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.
➜  ~**
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community,

1. Check the closed repo, whether it has go.mod and go.sum files
2. Check the version of the go (go mod is enforced in recent version meaning)
3. Check and learn about go mod and how to use (https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules)